# Prove: $f: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R, f(x,y)=xy\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}$ is continious

Tags: analysis, continuity

Why is $$f: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R, f(x,y)=xy\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}, f(0,0)=0$$ continuous in $(0,0)$?

I know that $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}[xy\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}]=^!0$. But how do I get to control the denominator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that
$$
|f(x)|\le \frac{|x||y|(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2}=|x||y| \qquad \forall (x,y)\ne (0,0),
$$
therefore
$$
0\le \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}|f(x,y)|\le \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}|x||y|=0,
$$
i.e.
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}f(x,y)=0=f(0,0).
$$
This shows that $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$. It follows that $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2$ .

Answer (score 4):

\begin{align*}
\left|xy\cdot\dfrac{x^{2}-y^{2}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\right|&\leq|xy|\cdot\dfrac{x^{2}+y^{2}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\\
&=|xy|,
\end{align*}
we know that $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}|xy|=0$, so by Squeeze Theorem we have $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}f(x,y)=0=f(0,0)$.

Answer (score 2):

If it is, then we **must** have $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\dfrac{xy(x^2-y^2)}{x^2+y^2}=0$$

Let's convert to polar. Let $x=r\cos\theta$, $y=r\sin\theta$. Then limit becomes:

$$\lim_{r\to 0}\dfrac{r^2\cos\theta\sin\theta(r^2\cos^2\theta-r^2\sin^2\theta)}{r^2}=\lim_{r\to 0}\dfrac{(r^2\cos\theta\sin\theta )r^2(\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta)}{r^2}$$

Clearly we have $r^4$ on top, $r^2$ on bottom, and thus the limit will go to $0$, hence it actually does exist. I think its easier to see via polar then bounding via squeeze thereom, but thats upto you

Answer (score 2):

The other answers seem to assume that you know that $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} |xy| = 0$

To avoid using this fact, simply use the definition.

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Choose $\delta = \sqrt{\epsilon}$. Then, for $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R²}$ such that $\Vert (x,y)\Vert < \delta$, we can find the inequalities $|x| < \delta$ and $|y| < \delta$.

And hence, $$|f(x,y) - f(0,0)| =\left| xy \frac{x²-y²}{x²+y²}\right| \leq \left| xy \frac{x²+y²}{x²+y²}\right| \ = |xy| = |x||y| < \delta² = \epsilon$$

whenever $\Vert (x,y)\Vert < \delta$.

Answer (score 1):

Here $|f(x,y)-f(0,0)|=\left |xy\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}-0\right|=\left |xy\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}\right|=|x||y|\left|\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}\right|\le |x||y|\le x^2+y^2< \epsilon$ if $x^+y^2< \delta^2(=\epsilon)$. So $f(x,y)$ is continuous at $(0,0)$